# Facebook Connect - take email attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an application in which uses the Facebook API. Facebook Connect. 
Turns out I can not get the email attribute. 
What is the problem?

```
FB.init({
            appId  : 'CODE',
            status: true, 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true, 

        });

        function statusFacebook() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                        FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
                            var nome = resp.name;
                            var email = resp.email;
                            var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                        });
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                        loginFacebook(); // nao autorizado, solicitar login
                }
                else {
                        loginFacebook(); // nao autorizado, solicitar login
                }});
        }

        function loginFacebook() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
                            var nome = resp.name;
                            var email = resp.email;
                            var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                        }, {scope: 'email'});
                    }
            });
        }
```

Have permissions and others but not work.
the button is: `<a href="##" onClick="statusFacebook();">Login Facebook</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function loginFacebook() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
                            var nome = resp.name;
                            var email = resp.email;
                            var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        });
                    }
            }, {scope: 'email'});
        }
```

As written in the [specs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), the `scope` must be declared as second param to `FB.login()` function:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: i make this, but the solution is create a fb-button with scope and in event onlogin call the function.. thanks!!